# Error message when trying to retrieve a value from a range using VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I've got an excel spreadsheet where I would normally use a VLOOKUP.

In this case I need to find the ID of the record when comparing email addresses, so the email address is the unique id here.

For example on sheet 1

```
    A             B              C            D
Person Id  |  Family Name  | First Name | Email
   #N/A    |  Doe          | John       | jd@email.com
```

On Sheet 2

```
    A             B              C            D
Person Id  |  Family Name  | First Name | Email
12345      |  Doe          | John       | jd@email.com
```

Basically on sheet 1 I've got 800 records, on sheet 2 450. I know the 450 are in Sheet 1, so I need to find the ids of those, and put them on sheet 1 where I've got lots more data for each person.

What I've tried so far is a VLOOKUP, but I keep getting an error. I'd like to do it with some sort of formula and not using any copy paste and remove duplicates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting an error most likely because your lookup value is located to the right of the value you are trying to retrieve in your source (**Sheet2**, in your case).

Basically, your current formula should work if your source data sheet (**Sheet2**) is arranged this way:

```
 A                 B              C            D
Email           |  Family Name  | First Name | Person ID
jd@email.com    |  Doe          | John       | XXXXXXX
```

where the **Person ID** column can placed in columns **B**, **C** or **D** ( as long as it's to the right of the **Email** column).

***To avoid having to rearrange your data***, instead of using `VLOOKUP`, I recommend using an `INDEX/MATCH` combo in column **A** of **Sheet1**, something along the lines of:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,match(D1,Sheet2!D:D,0),1)
```

where
`D1` is your lookup value  (email address)
`Sheet2!A:A` contains Person IDs
`Sheet2!D:D` contains Emails

Comment: Glad to help. Welcome to SuperUser!

Comment: @pnuts I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @pnuts Ah I see now. I'll update my answer.