# Combination of IF and VLOOKUP formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a cell that refers to more than one worksheet and displays the result (value) when it finds the product from the two sheets. SheetA has two columns, of which column `A` is the value and column `B` is that product name. SheetB only has product name.

Below is my formula but it fails to display result of product value, instead it always displays `Not Found` even though the product is found from the sheets.

Is there anything wrong with the formula?

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A35,'SheetA'!A:B,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A35,'SheetB'!D19:D115,1,FALSE),"Not Found"))

Comment: Hi @Neo, please [have a look at this question](http://superuser.com/questions/431362/error-message-when-trying-to-retrieve-a-value-from-a-range-using-vlookup) and see if it answers your question. If it doesn't please elaborate on what didn't work

Comment: That case involve only 2 sheets.  For my case, i am working on 3 sheets.  Lookup value on SheetC which refer to columns from SheetA and SheetB.

Answer (score 1):

> The content of A35 will not be found by the first VLOOKUP (see @Ivo Flipse). So it will be searched for in SheetB, where if present in range D19:D115, it will be found. It has not been, hence "Not found". Formula is fine, whether or not in SheetC, your description maybe not.
>
> — [Comment](https://superuser.com/questions/446599/excel-2007-combination-of-if-and-vlookup-formula#comment527554_446599) by [pnuts](https://superuser.com/users/145438/pnuts)